# how to center glyphicon in a navbar

Tags: html, glyphicons

I am trying to have 3 icons in a navbar at positions left, right and center
The left and right ones are at correct position but the center link is not in the center but towards the left i.e. contiguous with the left glyphicon
Any idea how to center it?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
         <a href="/left_link" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-left hidelink">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Left
         </a>
         <a href="/center_link" class="btn btn-info btn-lg hidelink">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Center
         </a>
         <a href="/right_link" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right hidelink">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Right
        </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `text-center` class to your container div:

```
<div class="container text-center">
```

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/XAF0maDUVl)**

Comment: thanx for the help